# c++ dynamic memory allocation causing corrupted heap

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, heap-corruption

not looking for an answer on this one, but some direction would be appreciated. Everywhere I have looked and all answers I have tried do not solve the problem.

I have instructions that state "Dynamically allocate variable to exactly what the user inputs. Can not use a placeHolder variable (userInput[256}]) to catch the input. append '\0' to end."

My original code is:

```
int main(){

    char cont = 'y';
    char *userInput = nullptr;

    while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y')
    {

        int ptrLength = 0;
        userInput = new char[ptrLength];

        cout << "Please enter a word or phrase: ";//2. Asks the user to enter any string (any sequence of characters)
        while (cin.peek() != '\n'){
            cin >> userInput[ptrLength];
            ptrLength++;
        }
        //1. You must use a pointer to a C-string and dynamically allocate just enough memory to store all the characters entered by the user PLUS the ‘\0’ char than must be appended at the end of the C-string.

        userInput[ptrLength] = '\0';        

        cout << endl;
        myVowels(userInput, ptrLength);
        cout << endl << endl;
        //delete [] userInput; //deleting here breaks the program. Not sure why right now.
        //userInput = nullptr;
        //5. The user must be asked if he/she wants to continue entering values or quit.
        cout << endl << "To enter another phrase press Y. To exit press any key." << endl;
        cin >> cont;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    }//end while cont = Y

    delete userInput;
    userInput = nullptr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Updated Code:

```
int main(){

    char cont = 'y';
    char *userInput = nullptr;

    while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y')
    {

        int num = 10;
        int ptrLength = num;
        userInput = new char[ptrLength];
        char *temp = nullptr;

        cout << "Please enter a word or phrase: ";//2. Asks the user to enter any string (any sequence of characters)
//FIX I FOUND, BUT IT DOES NOT WORK AT ALL
        while (cin.peek() != '\n'){
            cin >> userInput[ptrLength];
            if (ptrLength = num){
                num *= num;
                temp = new char[num];
                for (int i = 0; i < num/2; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = userInput[i];
                }
                delete [] userInput;
                userInput = temp;
                delete [] temp;
            }
        }
        //1. You must use a pointer to a C-string and dynamically allocate just enough memory to store all the characters entered by the user PLUS the ‘\0’ char than must be appended at the end of the C-string.

        userInput[ptrLength] = '\0';        

        cout << endl;
        myVowels(userInput, ptrLength);
        cout << endl << endl;

        //userInput = nullptr;
        //delete [] userInput; //This works, but by switching to nullptr I am not deleting the memory allocated. If I just have the delete with or without [] the program breaks. Tried with user input declared inside and outside of the WHILE statement. Heap is being corrupted.

        //5. The user must be asked if he/she wants to continue entering values or quit.
        cout << endl << "To enter another phrase press Y. To exit press any key." << endl;
        cin >> cont;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    }//end while cont = Y

    delete userInput;
    userInput = nullptr;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know the heap is being corrupted, I suspect from the way I am changing the allocated memory. I am not sure why the fix does not work it is in all the tutorials this way.

Comment: `(x^2)/2 != x` and `(ptrLength = num) != (ptrLength == num)`. And you free both your original and new character buffers. Maybe a rubber duck would help.

Comment: @JamesRoot `(x^2) != (x*x)` in C++

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I imagine your conversation with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would go at this point:

```
    int num = 10;
    int ptrLength = num;
    userInput = new char[ptrLength];
```

> You (talking to your rubber duck): Ok, so what the above boils down to
>   is that I allocated a buffer for ten characters. `userInput` here
>   points to ten characters, `userInput[0]` through `userInput[9]`.
>
> Rubber Duck: Ok.
>
> You: And both `num` and `ptrLength` are set to the value of 10.
>
> Rubber Duck: makes sense to me.

```
    while (cin.peek() != '\n'){
        cin >> userInput[ptrLength];
```

> You: So, I check if the next character read is a newline, if not, I
>   place the input in `userInput[ptrLength]`
>
> Rubber Duck: Wait, what's the initial value of `ptrLength`?
>
> You: 10, as I just said.
>
> Rubber Duck: But didn't you just say that you only have `userInput[0]`
>   through `userInput[9]`, allocated for your buffer, and writing
>   something to `userInput[10]`, at this point, will corrupt the heap.

So, what's your answer to your rubber duck's question here?

Answer (score 1):

- `userInput[ptrLength]` is out-of-range and must not be accessed after `userInput = new char[ptrLength];`.
- The condition `ptrLength = num` is not an equality test but an assignment and I guess it isn't what you want.
- You forgot to update `ptrLength` after reading.
- You deleted the newly allocated buffer and you made it unavailable.
- You should delete whatever you created via `new`.
- You must use `delete` *before* assgning `nullptr`. Also use `delete[]` for what is allocated via `new[]`.
- After `num = num*num;`, `num/2` won't generally be previous `num`. You have to calculate square root to obtain oid `num` from new `num`.

corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void myVowels(const char *userInput, int ptrLength){
    cout << "myVowels(" << userInput << ", " << ptrLength << ")\n";
}

int main(){

    char cont = 'y';
    char *userInput = nullptr;

    while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y')
    {

        int num = 10;
        int ptrLength = 0;
        userInput = new char[num];
        char *temp = nullptr;

        cout << "Please enter a word or phrase: ";//2. Asks the user to enter any string (any sequence of characters)
        while (cin.peek() != '\n'){
            cin >> userInput[ptrLength++];
            if (ptrLength == num){
                int oldNum = num;
                num *= num;
                temp = new char[num];
                for (int i = 0; i < oldNum; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = userInput[i];
                }
                delete [] userInput;
                userInput = temp;
            }
        }
        //1. You must use a pointer to a C-string and dynamically allocate just enough memory
        //   to store all the characters entered by the user PLUS the ‘\0’ char than must be
        //   appended at the end of the C-string.

        userInput[ptrLength] = '\0';

        cout << endl;
        myVowels(userInput, ptrLength);
        cout << endl << endl;

        delete [] userInput;
        userInput = nullptr;

        //5. The user must be asked if he/she wants to continue entering values or quit.
        cout << endl << "To enter another phrase press Y. To exit press any key." << endl;
        cin >> cont;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    }//end while cont = Y

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Duck Conversation helped as much as pointing out the other errors of my ways. I was able to focus and get the code working beyond crashability. Really appreciate the comments.